# Laravel Get Use id with session

Tags: php, laravel, session

Im trying to get the id of the logged in user. When the user is clicking on the button his id need to get send to the data base, But I get an error: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null.

This is my controller function:

```
    public function LendBook(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->session()->get('User_id');
        $book_id = $request->book_id;


        $q = new lend;
        $q->user_id = $user_id;
        $q->book_id = $book_id;

        $q->save();

        return 'test';
}
}
```

Comment: @chielvandijk i hope you get your correct answer

Comment: @chielvandijk please check it's working or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> here with this you get current user's id

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = $user->id;
```

Comment: @chielvandijk use can be added at the start of the controller

Comment: @chielvandijk did you check given solution is working or not ??

Answer (score 0):

```
public function LendBook(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $book_id = $request->book_id;

    $q = new Lend; // naming class should be Upper case "Lend"
    $q->user_id = $user_id;
    $q->book_id = $book_id;
    $q->save();

    return 'test';
}
```

Shorthand getting user id from current login user `auth()->user()->id;`

Adding Tips:
naming class should be Uppercase look the basic php standard (PSR) [enter link description here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question.

Comment: @xenooooo sorry i did update my answer, the PSR just tips for bestpractice using PHP